# Get key value from string using Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to get key value using Regex in powershell.

```
$string = "key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3"
$name = [Regex]::Matches($string, ':([^/]+),') | Select -ExpandProperty Value
Write-Host "Name :" $name
```

I want output like this :

```
$key1 = "value1"
$key2 = "value2"
$key3 = "value3"
```

Output i am getting :

```
Name : :value1,key2:value2,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the comma to separate the key:value pairs this should accomplish what you are after.

```
$string = "key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3"
$ht = @{} # declare empty hashtable
$string -split ',' | % { $s = $_ -split ':'; $ht += @{$s[0] =  $s[1]}} 
# split the string by ',', then split each new string on ':' and map them to the hashtable
```

Outputs the following (note by default they are not ordered)

```
PS C:\> $ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key3                           value3
key1                           value1
key2                           value2
```

Comment: You could achieve the same with `$string -replace ':','=' -split ',' | ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: Thanks....Perfect. I can easily access each key using $ht.key1, $ht.key2, $ht.key3

Comment: @LotPings This should be the answer- was unaware of this cmdlet!

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure that sysg0blin's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376422/9902555) can do the job, but if you really want to set specific variables this can be done with such script:

```
$string = "key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3"
$splitted = $string -split ','
$splitted | ForEach-Object {
  $i = $_ -split ":"
  Set-Variable -Name $i[0] -Value $i[1]
}
```

What you do here is to split string into array of `key:value` pair and then split each pair into array with 2 elements, first being variable name and second being value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You get that match because  there is no match before the `:` and `[^/]+` will also match `:` and `,`.

So your pattern will first match `:`, then it will match not a `/` and then backtracks until it can match a `,`

You could use 2 times a negated character class matching not a comma or colon and assert what is on the right is a comma or the end of the string:

```
[^:,]+:[^:,]+(?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kl26gY/1)

If you also don't want to match a `/` you could add it to the character class:

```
[^:,/]+:[^:,/]+(?=,|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you already have you answer, but here is one more way to do this.

```
("key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3").Split(',') | 
%{$PSItem | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header Name, Value}

# Results

Name Value 
---- ----- 
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```